# Android scales hdpi image on hdpi device

Tags: android, android-resources, hdpi

I have noticed that all the images in my application seems to be smaller than originals. For example.

I placed image on activity like this:

```
<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:src="@drawable/ic_search_dark"
           />
```

I took a screenshot from the result and measured the image as 25x25:

http://petromi.com/get/86b23cdb63.png

But in it's actual size is 28x28:

http://petromi.com/get/fd68913104.png

Image has been placed to `drawables-hdpi` folder. Device is 1280x800 tablet. I have logged its display metrics as follows:

```
Log.d("Screen (%s, %s) - [%s, %s] [%s]", dm.widthPixels, dm.heightPixels, dm.xdpi, dm.ydpi, dm.densityDpi);
```

And I got:

```
Screen (1280, 736) - [160.0, 160.15764] [213]
Screen (800, 1216) - [160.0, 160.15764] [213]
```

(for portrait and landscape)

It was a surprise for me that Android scales images from drawable-hdpi on hdpi device. Is it OK? If yes, can you guys give me a link where such rules are described?

Comment: Interesting - the numbers are correct. 28 * 213/240 = 24.85. The well-known doc says "Your application achieves "density independence" when it preserves the physical size (from the user's point of view) of user interface elements when displayed on screens with different densities."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the device registers as an `hdpi` device, it will take images from the `hdpi` folder.  It will then proceed to scale the image to the device's actual specs.  This is normal.

The dpi for `hdpi` is `240`.  What you have is `213`, so the image will still be scaled based on a `240 dpi` setting.

If you do not want scaling of any kind, then you need to put the image in the `drawable-nodpi` folder.